# Java; un programa que lea una frase y muestre las palabras en el orden inverso

Tags: java

Hola no sé como hacer este programa que lea una frase y la muestre a la inversa por ejemplo:

```
String frase = "Me gusta programar.";
```

y que muestre:

```
System.out.println("programar. gusta Me");
```

Gracias comunidad :D

Comment: quisiera ayudarte pero debes formular bien tu pregunta, con tu codigo que hayas intentado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes pasarlo a un array, luego recorrerlo del final hacia el inicio para que recoja las ultimas cadenas e ir concatenandolo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String cadena="hola como estas";
        String [] array=cadena.split(" ");
        String invertido="";
        for(int i=array.length-1;i>=0; i--){
           invertido=invertido+" "+array[i];
        }
        System.out.println(invertido);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Con JAVA 8:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("hola que mas".split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))
            .descendingIterator()
            .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

> hola que mas > mas que hola

[Demo](https://repl.it/@meerkat999/GentleStarryAvians)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un array a partir de la cadena original para obtener las palabras:

```
 String frase = "Me gusta programar.";
 String[] strWords =  frase.split(" ");
```

posteriormente invertir los valores del array

```
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strWords);
   Collections.reverse(list);
```

de esta forma construir la cadena requerida.

Ejemplo:

```
    String  resultado ="";
    String frase = "Me gusta programar.";
    String[] strWords =  frase.split(" ");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strWords);
    Collections.reverse(list);

    for (String part : list) {
        resultado += part + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

para obtener como salida:

```
programar. gusta Me
```

Agrego un [ejemplo online](https://www.ideone.com/I0m4FE).

Answer (score 0):

Existe dos forma de hacer eso en java la primera es asi :

```html
String sCadena = "LineaDeCodigo";

for (int x=sCadena.length()-1;x>=0;x--)
  sCadenaInvertida = sCadenaInvertida + sCadena.charAt(x);
    System.out.println(sCadenaInvertida);
```

que fue la manera que te contestaron anteriormente.
pero existe otra manera mas limpio y facil de esta manera:

y la otra forma en la cual puedes usar un metodo de java y hacer mas facil es de la siguiente forma :

Definimos el String y lo cargamos en el StringBuffer:

```html
String cadena= "abuelita, abuelita";
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(cadena);
```

Ejecutamos el .reverse() del StringBuffer y convertirmos el StringBuffer en una cadena mediante el método .toString()

```
String sCadenaInvertida=builder.reverse().toString();
```

Algo muy sencillo y limpio en tu codigo.

Comment: La pregunta es para el inverso de palabras, no de caracteres.